# Can I willingly reject a SWIFT transaction?

Tags: international-transfer, fees, wire-transfer, swift

I live in Brazil and I have a broker account in Europe, provided by my company for stock options.

I've recently sold some of my stocks and done my first transaction of this kind (International Wire Transfer) to my bank account in Brazil.

I received the money in USD and I need to convert it to BRL, therefore I haven't done the reception of the transaction with my bank yet. I naively just realized my bank charges exorbitant fees during this conversion.

I am wondering if it is achievable and safe in the banking world to ask the bank to deny the transaction as to make the sum go back to my broker account, from which point I can use alternative channels to receive the money in Brazil.

Comment: Be aware that there may be more fees associated with stopping the transaction...

Comment: This is entirely up to the financial institutions you are doing business with. The best way is to contact them and find out the procedures and costs.